# TypeError: expecting numeric data

Tags: python, excel, oracle, pandas

I am having trouble figuring out what this error means as there is not much help with this question online already.

Is it saying that my Oracle table needs to only receive numbers not letters? That can't be the case because I have my columns set to allow `VarChar` so that both numbers and letters will fit.

I had thought it was due to my DataFrame having `NaN`s in it, so I replaced all of them with 0's and I still receive this error.

Ultimately, I would like to export all this data, which I parsed from an Excel file, to my Oracle table.

Any help solving this would be appreciated.

My DataFrame:

```
S USTAINABLE H ARVEST S ECTOR| QUOTA LISTING JUN 11 2013 Unnamed: 1  \
0                                     AVAILABLE QUOTA                0   
1                                                DATE         TRADE ID   
2                                              6/4/13           130196   
3                                             5/28/13           130158   
4                                              6/4/13           130210   
5                                             5/14/13           130079   
6                                              6/4/13           130187   
7                                              6/4/13           130208   
8                                             6/11/13           130249   
9                                              6/4/13           130204   
10                                            5/28/13           130148   
11                                            5/28/13           130149   
12                                            5/28/13           130157   
13                                            5/21/13           130105   
14                                            5/21/13           130106   
15                                             6/4/13           130205   
16                                            6/11/13           130250   
17                                             6/4/13           130206   
18                                            6/11/13           130248   
19                                       QUOTA TO BUY                0   
20                                               DATE         TRADE ID   
21                                            6/11/13           130239   
22                                            5/14/13           130074   
23                                            3/26/13           130006   
24                                            5/14/13           130075   
25                                             5/7/13           130023   
26                                            5/14/13           130039   
27                                                  1                0   

         Unnamed: 2     Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  
0                 0              0           0  
1   AVAILABLE STOCK         AMOUNT  SALE PRICE  
2           COD GBW          10000         0.6  
3           COD GBW            300         0.6  
4       HADDOCK GBE   UP TO 30,000      OFFERS  
5            PLAICE           1000        0.45  
6        WHITE HAKE   UP TO 25,000         0.5  
7        WHITE HAKE           4000         0.5  
8         WINTER GB           3300        0.25  
9         WINTER GB          10000        0.48  
10        WINTER GB   1U0P 0T,0O00        0.25  
11        WINTER GB   UP TO 10,000         0.4  
12        WINTER GB           1400        0.25  
13        WINTER GB          10000         0.5  
14        WINTER GB          10000         0.5  
15       WINTER GOM           1000        0.38  
16       WINTER SNE           6500         0.4  
17       WINTER SNE           3000        0.63  
18   YELLOWTAIL GOM           2000        1.25  
19                0              0           0  
20    DESIRED STOCK         AMOUNT   BUY PRICE  
21          COD GOM   UP TO 14,000         2.1  
22          COD GOM          20000     INQUIRE  
23          COD GBE            ANY         1.5  
24      HADDOCK GOM          10000     INQUIRE  
25      HADDOCK GOM    UP TO 6,000        0.75  
26       WHITE HAKE  UP TO 100,000         0.3  
27                0              0           0  
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

My code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
import re
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("sole.noaa.gov", "1526", "sole")
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="user", password="password$", dsn=dsnStr)

path = 'Z:\\excel_file_to_parse'

pattern = re.compile(r'Listing(.+)', re.IGNORECASE)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
        #print("df is:", df)

        a = pattern.findall(str(df))
        print("a:", a)

        new_a = str(a)
        print("new_a:", new_a)

        #datetime_object = datetime.strptime(new_a, '%b %d %Y')
        #print("date:", datetime_object)

        print("row 1:", df.loc[0])

        df = df.fillna(0)
        print("df wihtout 0's is:", df)


cursor = con.cursor()
exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]
sql_query = ("INSERT INTO ROUGHTABLE(species, date_posted, stock_id, pounds, money, sector_name, ask)" "VALUES(:3, :1, :2, :4, :5, 'Sustainable Harvest Sector', '1')")


cursor.executemany(sql_query, exported_data)
con.commit() #commit to database

cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Printout of `exported_data`:

```
exported_data: [('AVAILABLE QUOTA', 0, 0, 0, 0), ('DATE', 'TRADE ID', 'AVAILABLE STOCK', 'AMOUNT', 'SALE PRICE'), ('6/4/13', 130196, 'COD GBW', 10000, 0.6), ('5/28/13', 130158, 'COD GBW', 300, 0.6), ('6/4/13', 130210, 'HADDOCK GBE', 'UP TO 30,000', 'OFFERS'), ('5/14/13', 130079, 'PLAICE', 1000, 0.45), ('6/4/13', 130187, 'WHITE HAKE', 'UP TO 25,000', 0.5), ('6/4/13', 130208, 'WHITE HAKE', 4000, 0.5), ('6/11/13', 130249, 'WINTER GB', 3300, 0.25), ('6/4/13', 130204, 'WINTER GB', 10000, 0.48), ('5/28/13', 130148, 'WINTER GB', '1U0P 0T,0O00', 0.25), ('5/28/13', 130149, 'WINTER GB', 'UP TO 10,000', 0.4), ('5/28/13', 130157, 'WINTER GB', 1400, 0.25), ('5/21/13', 130105, 'WINTER GB', 10000, 0.5), ('5/21/13', 130106, 'WINTER GB', 10000, 0.5), ('6/4/13', 130205, 'WINTER GOM', 1000, 0.38), ('6/11/13', 130250, 'WINTER SNE', 6500, 0.4), ('6/4/13', 130206, 'WINTER SNE', 3000, 0.63), ('6/11/13', 130248, 'YELLOWTAIL GOM', 2000, 1.25), ('QUOTA TO BUY', 0, 0, 0, 0), ('DATE', 'TRADE ID', 'DESIRED STOCK', 'AMOUNT', 'BUY PRICE'), ('6/11/13', 130239, 'COD GOM', 'UP TO 14,000', 2.1), ('5/14/13', 130074, 'COD GOM', 20000, 'INQUIRE'), ('3/26/13', 130006, 'COD GBE', 'ANY', 1.5), ('5/14/13', 130075, 'HADDOCK GOM', 10000, 'INQUIRE'), ('5/7/13', 130023, 'HADDOCK GOM', 'UP TO 6,000', 0.75), ('5/14/13', 130039, 'WHITE HAKE', 'UP TO 100,000', 0.3), (1, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: `exported_data = [tuple(x) for x in df.values]` is changing each field of data from a string into a tuple.  That's likely not what you want at all and is likely responsible for the data being sent not matching what you'd expect.  Print out `exported_data` prior to your call to `cursor.executemany`

Comment: Ok I printed it out and added the printout into my question. I am not an expert with SQL statements but I've been using that `[tuple(x) for x in df.values]` method for some time now and it has been working perfect until now. I'm not telling you you're wrong I'm just letting you know that that line hasn't given me major problems until now.

Comment: Are you saying that I should the `exported_data` line into something like `[str(x) for x in df.values]` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would expect.  It is not entirely clear without your table's schema though.

Comment: Well trying `exported_data = [str(x) for x in df.values]` resulted in the error `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number` so I'm still stuck :(    Researching these errors reveals they could be due to anything involving bind variables, date formats, trying to export a string vs a dict, and more. But the thing is, I have been using this exact method successfully to export a ton of files. But now it decides to fail for these and I can't figure out why

Comment: Does read_excel return the headers of the spreadsheet?  Are you skipping the header row?  Typically the headers would have different formats than the data and that would account for odd failures like trying to store a string in a field that requires a number, etc.

Comment: Yeah I skip the first row that has nothing of value with `df = df.ix[1:]` but that hasn't solved anything either. The printouts of `exported_data` from this file and another one that actually succeeds are pretty much identical, which is even more confusing